# Vim go to previous cursor position when switching to a buffer

Tags: vim

I switch from buffer 1 to buffer 2 and my cursor is at line 100. I use j/k to scroll around and land at line 120. Then I use ctrl-O to switch back to buffer 1, and then ctrl-I to go to buffer 2.

I expect that the cursor should be at line 120, as that is where I left off, but to my annoyance, the cursor is at line 100. How can I get vim to go to line 120?

Comment: I don't think j/k are considered jumps, so they don't modify the jumplist (otherwise you'd land on every single movement when you do Ctrl-o, which would be pretty useless). You can use `m'` to manually place the current location into jumplist.

Comment: @Amadan, Good point. Would this be possible: remap ctrl+o to call a function, which checks the jump list. If the previous jump location is in a different buffer, change the current jump location's cursor to the current cursor, so that when i ctrl+i back, I return to exactly where I left off?

Comment: Dunno, it might work.

Answer (score 7):

The commands you are using are working as advertised. The problem is that you don't use the right commands for what you are trying to do.

`<C-o>` and `<C-i>` are not related to buffers *at all*. Their job is to let you move up and down the jump list, no more no less. The fact that they lead you to another buffer is *a side effect.* Don't rely on side effects: if you don't want to navigate the jump list, don't use them.

If you need to alternate between two buffers, the right command is `<C-^>` (or `<C-6>` on some keyboards).

If you need to switch to a specific buffer, use `:b <tab>` or `:ls` followed by `:bn` with `n` being the number of the desired buffer.